# defining block as method parameter gives a warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I got below warning

```
"success" used as the name of the previous parameter rather then as part of the selector
```

for this code part:

```
- (void) fetchAlbum:  success:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *))success
                  failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;
```

If I add a first parameter like these

```
- (void) fetchAlbum: (void) dummy success:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *))success
                  failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure;
```

the warning disappears.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you first declaration, when you put `:` it requires the parameter to be defined you can't leave it blank.. You can try to choose a method name like below

```
-(void)fetchAlbumWithSuccessCompletion:(void (^)(NSMutableArray *))success
                  failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure
```